# Is it possible to convert an executable to a dylib in OSX?

Tags: macos

I know that there are a few tools (otool, dwarfdump, etc) to examine an executable in OSX. What I'm wondering is this:

Is it possible to extract code from a command line executable and repackage it as a static or dynamic library (assume for the sake of argument that I have the headers for the exposed APIs I want to access). And if so, how would I go about it?